# How do you time a HTML element to disappear after a day?

Tags: javascript, html, post, timer, blogs

I am creating a website for my club and I want to put in a feature where, with each new blog post that I post, there is an image saying "New!" beside it. However, I want this image to disappear after a day. Can someone tell me how to time this image to only be visible for 24 hours?

Thanks

Comment: This needs to be done server side, not client side

Answer (score 1):

Old variable must be saved as default date.
example for capture date old:

```
date_limit=new Date();
temp1=date_limit.getTime();
temp2=parseInt(-1*24*60*60*1000);
total=date_limit.setTime(temp1+temp2);
```

At the time of check would be:

```
date_new=new Date();
if (date_new<date_limit)
{
    //show image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will usually be considered done on server side. Unless you are aiming to serve your page for someone particular who keeps your page open "forever" :P

Putting a timestamp on each of the post, is often called "Model".

Showing your page to any viewers comes to site is called "View".

So based on no knowledge of what is your implementation, I can't give you any code, but it would be similar to something like this,

```
if sucess_on_post:
    save_time_now()
```

And when you render the page, do something like this (it can be either in frontend or in backend),

```
posted_time = load_stored_time()
if now() > posted_time + 24 * 60 * 60:
    hide_label()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is done by PHP .

There are 2 thing that you could do. First of all you have to save the date/time that your blog has been added in another col. Then you have to check IF the blog date/time i NOT today .

So, if you choose to youse the [Date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function: [d.m.Y or 11.06.2015]
example:

```
   <?php
     $q = mysql_query(...);//your query
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
     $date = $r['date'] // the row that you had to create in mysql to write the  post date there ..   
      $today = date("d.m.Y"); // this wil output the TODAY date in the format from above [..]
       if($today == $date){ $new = "IT'S NEWWW !!! "; }else{ $new=" its not new :( ";}
       echo " blog post -> added in ".$date." -> $new <br />"; 
    } 
   ?>
```

Well, thats ok, but there is another way of saving the time, and thats by the [TIME()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function
example:

```
  $q = mysql_query(...);//your query
            $status = "";
         while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
            $date = $r['date']; // this wil output the datey in this way -> 124341241451 
            $now = time(); // NOW in ms
            $days_need_to_pass = 1; // how many days you want to say -> NEW
            if(  $date > ($now - ($days_need_to_pass * 86400)) )
            {
              $status = " <b>NEW</b> ";
            }
        echo "blog post -> added -> ".date("d.m.Y", $date)." -> ".$status." <br />";
         }
```

It's not simple but i hope you understand .. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try with this javascript:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#newimg').fadeOut('fast');
}, 86400000); // <- 24 hours in milliseconds
```